# Introduce "Mandatory" Methods to Implementors of an Interface

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, interface

The current implementation is pretty much aligns with a simple Strategy Design Pattern. There are multiple steps to be executed and these will be invoked provided by the following interface:

```
public interface ICommandStep
{
    void Execute(CommandParameters cParams);
    string StepName { get; }
}
```

Example implementor:

```
public class Step1 : ICommandStep {
    public string StepName => "Initial Step";
    public void Execute(CommandParameters cParams) {
        // instructions
    }
}
```

By now there many different classes implementing this interface, and I want to ensure all of them will have a pre and post step to execution. For example log state, params, StepName start and end.

How could I introduce a way to have `protected virtual void PreExecute` and `protected virtual void PostExecute` methods with common (overridable) logic and to make sure the method will always be invoked in this order:

```
1. PreExecute
2. Execute
3. PostExecute
```

Preferably without changing the Execute method in the implementor classes.

Introducing abstract class is possible.

Comment: You shouldn't, because you're enforcing *implementation details*. You could of course add those methods to the interface, but again, you're imposing on the internal implementation. **Why** do you feel the need to dictate how something is implemented beneath an interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare base class and define overridable methods in needed order:

```
public interface ICommandStep
{
    void Execute(CommandParameters cParams);
    string StepName { get; }
}

public abstract class CommandBase : ICommandStep
{
    public void Execute(CommandParameters cParams)
    {
        PreExecute();
        ExecuteInternal(cParams);
        PostExecute();
    }

    protected virtual void PostExecute()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void ExecuteInternal(CommandParameters cParams)
    {
    }

    protected virtual void PreExecute()
    {
    }

    public abstract string StepName { get; }
}

public class Step1 : CommandBase
{
    public override string StepName => "Initial Step";
    protected override void ExecuteInternal(object cParams)
    {
        // instructions
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working well. I like the structure. The only drawback is that it needs some change in all implementing classes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding new methods to the interface will necessarily mean breaking the existing implementations. If implementation is optional then you should use an `abstract` class instead of an `interface`.

An alternative exists by adding a new interface and adding a runtime type-check in an extension method, like so:

```
public interface ICommandStep
{
    void Execute(CommandParameters cParams);
    string StepName { get; }
}

public interface ICommandStep2 : ICommandStep
{
    void PreExecute()
    void PostExecute()
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Execute2(this ICommandStep step, CommandParameters cParams)
    {
        if( step is ICommandStep2 step2 )
        {
            step2.PreExecute();
            step2.Execute( cParams );
            step2.PostExecute();
        }
        else
        {
            step2.Execute( cParams );
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ICommandStep[] steps = ...
foreach( ICommandStep step in steps )
{
    step.Execute2( cmdParams );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 solutions:

1. Template Method pattern as proposed by Backs.
2. Decorator Pattern together with factory. Decorator pattern is great when you want to execute some code before/after call to other object. Factory is to ensure that each created object will be decorated.

Example implementation of 2.:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the component in Decorator Pattern
    /// </summary>
    public interface ICommandStep
    {
        void Execute(String cParams);
        string StepName { get; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the concrete component in Decorator Pattern
    /// </summary>
    public class ConcreteStep1 : ICommandStep
    {
        public string StepName
        {
            get
            {
                return "1";
            }
        }

        public void Execute(string cParams)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"STEP {StepName}: EXECUTE");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the decorator in Decorator Pattern
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class StepDecorator : ICommandStep
    {
        protected ICommandStep _commandStep;
        public abstract string StepName
        {
            get;
        }
        public StepDecorator(ICommandStep commandStep)
        {
            this._commandStep = commandStep;
        }
        public abstract void Execute(string cParams);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the concrete decorator in Decorator Pattern
    /// </summary>
    public class ConcreteStepDecorator : StepDecorator
    {
        public ConcreteStepDecorator(ICommandStep commandStep) : base(commandStep) { }

        public override string StepName
        {
            get
            {
                return _commandStep.StepName;
            }
        }

        public override void Execute(string cParams)
        {
            // You can do whatever you want before / after execution of command
            Console.WriteLine($"STEP {_commandStep.StepName}: PRE EXECUTE");
            _commandStep.Execute(cParams);
            Console.WriteLine($"STEP {_commandStep.StepName}: POST EXECUTE");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is a Simple Factory. You encapsulate here creation of ICommandStep, so that it will always be decorated
    /// </summary>
    public class SimpleStepFactory
    {
        public ICommandStep createStep()
        {
            return new ConcreteStepDecorator(new ConcreteStep1());
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var step = new SimpleStepFactory().createStep();
            step.Execute("params");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This solution has couple of advantages:

- You can wrap your steps with many decorators, i.e. you can wrap step in decorator that shows it's name and wrap these two in another decorator that shows the parameters
- You don't have to modify your steps, because all the extra work is handled by decorators

Comment: Do you have some examples for these solutions?

Comment: I've added code example with Decorator Pattern to my original comment. Template Method pattern was already shown by Backs.